# execute() and executeUpdate() methods are implemented in

Tags: java

execute() and executeUpdate() methods are of Statement Interface of java.sql package. But these are not default methods hence these are abstract methods so where is the implementation of these methods?

Comment: @ankur they're implemented in the specific JDBC driver you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html) is an abstraction for a class that the loaded [JDBC driver](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) must provide a concrete implementation for that works with the specific database you're using. Every database has slightly different requirements.

It's buried inside the library, but you don't have to worry about that if you use proper dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

Object who implements Statement interface may be generated using another object who implements Connection interface, for example:

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
 Statement  stmt = conn.createStatement()
```